# How to effectively compare two decimal values in c#

Tags: c#

I have three values that I post in my windows Form.

```
Value A: 97.65
Value B: 2
Total: 195.6
```

I have a function that checks if the total does not exceed the threshold of `300000`.

```
public bool isValidAmount(decimal valA, int valB, decimal total) 
{
   int threshold = 300000;
   int calcTotalAmount = (int) Math.Ceiling(valA * valB);
   int totalToInt = (int) Math.Ceiling(total);
 
   if ((calcTotalAmount == totalToInt) && calcTotalAmount <= threshold) 
   {
      return true;
   }
   else if (calcTotalAmount != totalToInt) 
   {
      return false;
   }
   else if (calcTotalAmount > threshold) 
   {
      return false;
   }

}
```

My issue is that the first condition is always met since my input Total is less than 300000. How can I make sure the validation is performed effectively? Please help.

But when you multiply 97.65 *2 = 195.3.

Comment: Have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @mjwills: Is there an alternative way than to converting it to int and comparing? Because my total that I have inputted should be matched with the multiplication rather.

Comment: Use `==` or `<=` or `>=`. As a general rule, that is how you compare decimals to one another.

Comment: the signature of your function is invalid. Also, please describe what you need exactly, your variable names and description are not obvious at all. Currently, I'm tempted to rewrite your whole function as `const int threshold = 300_000; return total <= threshold;`, (or pass threshold as a parameter)

Comment: It's not clear why you want to round / use ceiling. Is that part of your requirements? Otherwise I'd suggest to drop this.

Comment: I want to the total inputted to match the `valA *valB`

Comment: What is "threshold" suppsoed to mean here, then?

Comment: The total inputted and the calcTotalAmount should not exceed the value of the threshold.

Comment: Did you try `var calcTotalAmount = valA * valB; return (calcTotalAmount == total && calcTotalAmount <= threshold);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var valueA = 1.0;
var valueB = 400000;
var total = 400000.0;
var check = isValidAmount((decimal)valueA, valueB, (decimal)total);
```

**Dont forget to cast to decimal when passing the parameters to the isValidAmount() method**

Then write your method as follows,

```
public bool isValidAmount(decimal valA, int valB, decimal total) 
{
   var threshold = 300000;
   var calcTotalAmount = (int) Math.Ceiling(valA * valB);
   var totalToInt = (int) Math.Ceiling(total);

   if (calcTotalAmount == totalToInt && calcTotalAmount <= threshold) 
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

*You do not need Math.Ceiling(), but I dont know your requirement so I have included that as well*